# How to access variable properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let name = document.querySelector('.listing-name').innerText;
  let street = document.querySelector('.street').innerText;
  let call =  document.querySelector(".ion-android-call").innerText;
  return name + "^" + street + "^" + call;
});

await console.log(textContent.name);
```

I want to access here `textContent.name` but it prints `undefined` value.

How to access the properties?

Is it possible to access the properties of `textContent`?

Comment: `textContent` is being set _equal_ to the return of `page.evaluate`, not having it assigned as a property.  You should be able to simply `console.log` `textContent`-- _ASSUMING_ that `page.evaluate` somehow returns the value of whatever is returned from the function it is passed as an argument.  Also, what's with all the `await`?  I don't know about your `page.evaluate` function but `console.log` is _not_ asynchronous.  You may want to reevaluate your understanding of what `await` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose other properties of local block by returning it.

```
const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let name = document.querySelector('.listing-name').innerText;
  let street = document.querySelector('.street').innerText;
  let call =  document.querySelector(".ion-android-call").innerText;
  return 
    {
     content: name + "^" + street + "^" + call,
     name: name ,
     street : street,
     call : call
});
```

No you can access original result by `textContent.content` and name using  `textContent.name`.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander said in his comment in this case textContent is not an object but only a string. If you would like to access the different values without changing it from a string you could use [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like

```
console.log(textContent.split('^')[ 0 ])
```

To automagically split the textContent variable up into an array based on the locations where '^' exist (and also removing them in the process).

If you would like to make it an Object-based approach you would need to modify your code in the call to `page.evaluate` to fit, something like

```
const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let name = document.querySelector('.listing-name').innerText;
  let street = document.querySelector('.street').innerText;
  let call =  document.querySelector(".ion-android-call").innerText;
  return {
    name: name,
    street: street,
    call: call
  }
});

await console.log(textContent.name);
```

You could also create a single variable Object and set the properties and values inside of it and then return it which would eliminate 2/3 local variables, or use return directly as above but instead set the property values inside of it and use no variables. But whatever is the most readable for you tends to be the best way for you to write your own code, at least until you decide to change your style (or it evolves naturally).